# My 4 Xeon E7 have lower performances than a single 8th Gen i5

Tags: cpu, performance, hardware-failure, intel-core-i5, xeon

I have an open question for you :

I set up a second hand server in my office to train our ML models on it ; it contains 4 Xeon E7 4820 (https://ark.intel.com/products/53675/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E7-4820-18M-Cache-2_00-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI) - 2,00GHz, 8 cores, 16 threads each -, 128Gbs of RAM and 128GB of SWAP (SSD Swap).

However, I did my first test learning on it, and very surprisingly it was amazingly... slow. 11 minutes to train, when it takes 5 minutes to train on my 8th gen i5 cpu (1,6GHz, 4 cores, 8 threads) with 8Gb of RAM and 8Gbs of swap.

Htop tells me that parallel computing is on, and the CPU load spikes are about 3 for the i5 and 22 for the 4 E7 ; so do you have any idea why there is such a gap of performance ? I know thay Moore's law is an irresistible phenomenon, but for a 1 year old middle end CPU to outperform 4 seven year old Xeon E7, I can't wrap my head arround this one. Hope you can help ! :)

PS : I already installed Cuda and CuDNN on it but it doesn't work yet and I performed the learning with CPU only. I was so baffled by the results that I stopped working on GPU acceleration (we have a small 1050 Ti I installed on the server) altogether to work on the problem. I made sure the exact same code is running on both computers too.

Thanks in advance ! :)

Frost

Comment: What CPU does the I5 have?

Comment: There it is, intel core i5 8250U : https://ark.intel.com/products/124967/Intel-Core-i5-8250U-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (as with most machine learning problems) is probably to do with memory bandwidth.

Machine learning isn't particularly CPU calculation intensive, they do a lot of "easy" calculations, but is heavily limited by bandwidth to memory. This is one of the reasons that graphics card stream processors are so good for it. Each stream processor is relatively limited (compared to a CPU) but for simpler operations their massive bandwidth and sheer number of processors more than makes up for their limitations.

To pick a random [8th generation i5](https://ark.intel.com/products/126685/Intel-Core-i5-8600K-Processor-9M-Cache-up-to-4_30-GHz):

```
Max Memory Bandwidth    41.6 GB/s
```

[CPUboss](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Xeon-E7-4820-v2-vs-Intel-Xeon-E7-4820) seems to suggest that the memory bandwidth of a first generation E7-4820 is 23GB/s (23,464 MB/s)

A multiprocessor machine will need to be constantly copying memory across CPUs or otherwise sharing access to memory from one CPU to another.

The combination of shared memory and substantially lower bandwidth to begin with is probably what is hurting the older system.

Newer Xeons claim upwards of 85GB/s bandwidth.

Comment: I didn't think about it, that would explain everything, including the fact that the same difference was observable for comparable CPUs. Thanks!

Do you think there is any way I could still take advantage of this server ? (it definitely has some decent computing power, it would be a shame not to use it)

Comment: With significantly more RAM there's nothing stopping you from using it for larger models that you don't mind taking a bit longer over, it would probably be faster when the amount of memory used exceeds the system RAM of the i5. Apart from that I couldn't really begin to guess what else you might be able to use such a machine for...

Comment: Well, you were very helpful, thanks a lot! One of the main advantages of the machine was that it has many slots available for GPUs, so I'll swiftly get back to GPU optimization :) Thanks again !

Comment: With the 4 CPUs I would assume that they all have an equal amount of memory spread across them, in theory each processor could be training a set of models individually so if you needed 4 subtly different models done at the same time then again the Xeons would probably be faster overall. You'd just need to work out how to use a specific processor and it's attached RAM. Then you would have a (theoretical) total bandwidth of 92GB/s, albeit only when doing 4 sets instead of one.

Comment: If you want to efficiently use the multi-processor machine, you need to take into account its NUMA configuration. A CPU should mostly access directly connected memory. Dunno if anyone wrote ML software with NUMA in mind.

Comment: Well, I'll check this out. However, I set everything up for the GTX 1050Ti and my learning time went down from 11 minutes to 25 seconds, so I'd say it's more interesting to multiply GPUs rather than trying to exploit those CPUs. It's a bit of a shame, but I got a good second hand deal so it's alright :) I'll keep you posted if I come across solutions to dispatch operations separately to multiple CPUs, thanks again everyone ! :)